# hyperref and \addcontentsline's patch in expl3 block

Tags: hyperref, expl3, patching

I want to patch `\addcontentsline` command for changing `\thepage` to `\thechapter--\thepage`. However I found that things went wrong when I used expl block:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
% \usepackage{hyperref}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\patchcmd{\addcontentsline}{\thepage}{\thechapter--\thepage}{\typeout{toc~succeed}}{\typeout{toc~fail}}
\ExplSyntaxOff
% \patchcmd{\addcontentsline}{\thepage}{\thechapter--\thepage}{\typeout{toc succeed}}{\typeout{toc fail}}
\begin{document}
  \tableofcontents
  \section{one}
  \chapter{text}
  \section{two}
\end{document}
```

If I didn't load `hyperref` package, the patch can be done both inside and outside expl block: terminal types `tocsucceed`;

[image]

If I load `hyperref` package, the patch can't be done inside expl block: terminal types `tocfail`, but can be done outside expl block.

Why would this happen?

Comment: When patching all involved tokens must have the same catcode as at definition time. The definition of hyperref contains spaces and a colon, which have a different catcode in expl3.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I see, there is a `bookmark\temp@online:\MessageBreak` in hyperref-defined `\addcontentsline`, so it breaks `\patchcmd`? Also, if I want to patch this in a `explpackage`, I have to use `\ExplSyntaxOff` to exit expl environment and finish it?

Comment: Ah you said **space** would also break `\patchcmd` in expl3, even a simple linebreak? So can I say that if I want to patch a command from latex2e, I should work under 2e environment?